# Create document workspace

Tags: document, library, workspace

When I try to create new document workspace from file in library, SharePoint 2010 creates a document workspace but does not copy source file. There is only an empty sub-site with empty "Shared documents" library.

How can I create a document workspace containing the file with possibility "Publish to source location"? I tried to upload file and send it from source library, but this option is still missing. Setting custom send to destination isn't the solution for me.